# Xamarin.Forms How to show a notification even app is closed

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I am Using **Xamarin.Fomrs** PLC Project, I am trying to show a notification even app is closed, right now it is working fine when app is running because I put the Notification thread on `OnStart()`,What I should do to make Notification working even if app is closed

On The Following A brief of code to be more clearly :

```
namespace X
{
    public class App : Application
    {
        INotificationService service;           
    }


    void CheckNotifications ()
    {
        service = DependencyService.Get<INotificationService> ();
        service.Notify (message);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep (1000 * 60);          
     }

     protected override void OnStart ()
     {          
            var threadStart = new System.Threading.ThreadStart (CheckNotifications);
            var thread = new System.Threading.Thread (threadStart);
            thread.IsBackground = true;
            thread.Start ();
     }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am Using Xamarin.Fomrs PLC Project, I am trying to show a notification even app is closed

You need to [Register a start Service](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/services/creating-a-service/) and show a notification in this start service:

```
[Service(Exported =true,Name = "demo.winffee.MYSERVICE")]
[IntentFilter(new string[] {"demo.winffee.MYSERVICE"})]
public class MyService : Service
{
    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    [return: GeneratedEnum]
    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, [GeneratedEnum] StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        string msg=intent.GetStringExtra("msg");
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(msg)) {
            Toast.MakeText(this, msg, ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
        return base.OnStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    public override void OnDestroy()
    {
        base.OnDestroy();
    }
}
```

Notes: `[Service(Exported =true,Name = "demo.winffee.MYSERVICE")]` is necessary part to call this service out of application.

And call the service from other application:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("demo.winffee.MYSERVICE");
intent.PutExtra("msg", "this is the text message from another application");
StartService(intent);
```